# Why My SpringBoot Project use Mybatis have mybatis wroing with differnet platform environment

Tags: docker, mybatis

My project is SpringBoot+Mybatis。I runing it on the windows is Ok,but when it run on the docker (centos),it run the wrong as follows as.  It seems can't receive the parameter.

2022/05/27 17:30:57.188 [http-nio-8003-exec-8] ERROR c.x.b.w.ExceptionAdvice - [globalException,121] - nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'user' not found. Available parameters are [arg3, arg2, param5, arg5, arg4, param6, arg1, arg0, param3, param4, param1, param2]

org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'user' not found. Available parameters are [arg3, arg2, param5, arg5, arg4, param6, arg1, arg0, param3, param4, param1, param2]

at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:77)

at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.selectList(Unknown Source)

at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:230)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.PageMapperMethod.executeForMany(PageMapperMethod.java:172)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.PageMapperMethod.execute(PageMapperMethod.java:85)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.PageMapperProxy.invoke(PageMapperProxy.java:64)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.selectAll(Unknown Source)

at cn.xiongdi.base.service.impl.SysLogServiceImpl.getAllByPage(SysLogServiceImpl.java:64)

at cn.xiongdi.base.service.impl.SysLogServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fbd87511.invoke()

at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)

at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)

at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)

at cn.xiongdi.base.service.impl.SysLogServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fd496b0b.getAllByPage()

at cn.xiongdi.base.web.SysLogController.getAll(SysLogController.java:63)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)

at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)

at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)

Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'user' not found. Available parameters are [arg3, arg2, param5, arg5, arg4, param6, arg1, arg0, param3, param4, param1, param2]

at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$ParamMap.get(MapperMethod.java:204)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicContext$ContextAccessor.getProperty(DynamicContext.java:115)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2685)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTProperty.getValueBody(ASTProperty.java:114)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTNotEq.getValueBody(ASTNotEq.java:50)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:470)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:434)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.OgnlCache.getValue(OgnlCache.java:44)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.ExpressionEvaluator.evaluateBoolean(ExpressionEvaluator.java:32)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.IfSqlNode.apply(IfSqlNode.java:34)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:33)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.TrimSqlNode.apply(TrimSqlNode.java:55)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicSqlSource.getBoundSql(DynamicSqlSource.java:41)

at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement.getBoundSql(MappedStatement.java:292)

at com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor.intercept(PageInterceptor.java:83)

at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.query(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:148)

at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)

at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433)

Comment: The project must be compiled with `-parameters` compiler option. 'How' depends on your project's setup. If you use Maven, for example, you need to configure `compilerArgs` of [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs).

Comment: Thank you,I solved the problem as you said. And I also configure the parameter of mybatis configuration parameter as follow:
```configuration:
    use-actual-param-name: true
```

Comment: You're welcome! Just FYI, `useActualParamName` is enabled by default.